# Can one distinguish between near and far field for gravitational radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, gravitational-waves

For electromagnetic radiation one usually distinguishes between near and far field. The wave equation for the far field are based on Maxwell equations for the vacuum and predict that the radiated power density falls of with an inverse square law. From what I know, the near field is described by the [inhomogeneous electromagnetic wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhomogeneous_electromagnetic_wave_equation) and predicts that the radiated power density falls of with an inverse cube law. Can one also distinguish in the same manner between near and far field of gravitational radiation?

Comment: This is an interesting question.  Off the top of my head, I would say that near enough to the source of gravitational radiation, the linear, weak-field approximation is no longer a good approximation in contrast with the EM equations which *are* linear.

Comment: [This](https://www.its.caltech.edu/~kip/scripts/.../II-68.pdf) might be helpful.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri the link is broken, but I have a keen interest in the same question right now. Do you have an updated link for that reference?

Comment: @PonderStibbons, I think this is the current link:

https://www.its.caltech.edu/~kip/index.html/PubScans/II-68.pdf

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Thanks, looks highly suitable for my purpose.